# imagemagick -contrast-stretch doesn't work (v6.7)

Tags: linux, imagemagick

Why doesn't `-contrast-stretch 15%` affect the output in this syntax?

```
convert -density 300 -trim test1.pdf -contrast-stretch 15% test1_%02d.png
```

Imagemagick version

```
root@amd-3700-2gb ~ # convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2013-09-01 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

The docs says it was implemented in v6.2

```
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#contrast-stretch
```

Comment: Can you add a link to your PDF and output image?

Comment: www.bluemachines.dk/pdf/test1.pdf www.bluemachines.dk/pdf/test1_00.png

Comment: test1_00.png has the same filesize both with and without `-contrast-stretch 15%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contrast-stretch does not work because the percentage is too low. Increasing it will modify the image but probably not give you the desired result.

If you are trying to cleanup the scanned image you might have more luck with the [textcleaner](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/) script from Fred Weinhaus.